# Select elements of the next row of a GridView

Tags: android, eclipse, gridview

I have this xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pantallaPrincipal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textoTitulo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5px"
        android:layout_marginRight="5px"
        android:layout_marginTop="5px"
        android:gravity="center" >
    </TextView>

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/gridPictos"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5px"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8px"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="15px" >
    </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the gridview runs correctly, but it is possible "jump" from the last element of the first row to the first element of the next row?

The final objective is that the user can contro the entire gridview using only the left and right keys.